# jQuery Disable SlideToggle in desktop resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a sidebar with 3 sections:

- In mobile resolutions, these sections appear like accordion tabs with only the header being visible, clicking on the anchor inside the **header** element triggers slideToggle which shows/hides rest of the content in that section. This works.
- In desktop resolutions, the 3 sections and it's entire content are always visible, so basically clicking on the header shouldn't do anything. When I load/refresh the page in desktop resolution, clicking the header anchor element doesn't do anything (which is great) but if I switch to mobile resolution and then switch back to desktop resolution then clicking on the header anchor element toggles the contents, so please let me know, how to stop this slideToggle effect in desktop.

jQuery Code:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){     

   if ($('#page-content').width() < 991 ) {

        $('#primary-sidebar header > a').click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).parent('header').siblings('.widget').slideToggle();
        });
   } else if ($('#page-content').width() > 992 ) {

        $('#primary-sidebar header > a').click(function(e) {
            return false;
        });
   }
});
```

Thanks!!!

Comment: Did you try the ```e.preventDefault();``` instead of returning false on desktop?

Comment: Yes, I did implement e.preventDefault() Also tried e.stopPropagation(), doesn't work unfortuantely.

Comment: First of all this code is so unoptimized. On each window resize new event handler will be added, it may be a lot lot more than 1.. You need clean click handler before you add it by `$('#primary-sidebar header > a').unbind('click')`

Comment: Thanks Max. That works.

Answer (score 0):

Although unbinding the click event worked, the `$(window).on('load resize', function(){` was creating issues, on resizing window, the slideToggle effect would run multiple times on single click. There is no need for the window resize/load line of code. The following is the code that works perfectly for me.

```
 $('#primary-sidebar header > a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var width = $('#page-content').width();

    if (width <= 991) {
        $(this).parent('header').siblings('.widget').slideToggle();
        $(this).find('.fa.fa-chevron-left').toggleClass('fa-chevron-down');
    } 
});
```